# How to split an alphabetic mapped list into multiple <ul> sorted by first letter with React?

Tags: reactjs

I map a list from an API and it is listed in alphabetic order.

```
                <ul>
                    {listItem.map((item, index) => (
                        <li>
                            <a
                                key={index}
                                data={item}
                            >
                                {item.name}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
```

How can I have this list split in multiple `<ul>` sorted by the first letter? Also, if it is possible, to have the first letter displayed before each `<ul>`. I have no clue from where to even start, since I am doing my first step not only into React, but programming. Any help  pointing out a solution or a direction is much appreciate. Thanks ever so much.

Comment: If you list is already in alphabetical order, you just need to split up by first letter. You can do a prepass before, and create a list of lists. Or you you need to keep track of which first letter you're currently outputting and change the HTML depending on that.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping. So I am gonna have a map inside another map? The first map I list all items and the second map I split them?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You can't list items in html and then rearrange them, yo have to do it before. If you have a list of lists, the first map applies your listing function to each list, and then that function will have a map for viewing the list. For example.

Comment: There's many ways to do this, do it in small steps: first output a list with the items in order: then try and display the first letter in that same list. Then maybe you'll see a pattern in how the data is processed, and you can split it up.

Comment: All right. I have something to start with. Will give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution with `reduce`. Here it is:

```
   const groupedList = listItem.reduce((acc, obj) => {
        const k = obj.name.charAt(0);
        acc[k] = acc[k] || [];
        acc[k].push(obj);
        return acc;
    }, {});
```

And then:

```
                    {
                        Object.values(groupedList).map((item, index) => {
                            return (
                                <ul key={index}>
                                    <h3>{item[0].name[0]}</h3>
                                    {item.map((item, index) => (
                                        <li key={index} data={item}>
                                            <a
                                                href={`/listItem/${item.slug}`}
                                            >
                                                {item.name}
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    ))}
                                </ul>
                            )
                        })
                    }
```

I hope this solution can help some other people.

Comment: Unbelievably clean code for someone as new as you said you were. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Also I recommend using `Lodash` library if you're not using already. It provides many convenience methods such as `groupBy` in this case.

```
// input list
A = [{name: 'Brussel'}, {name: 'Coil'}, {name: 'Anil'}, {name: 'Alan'}, {name: 'Bran'}]

// aggregation
groupBy = _.groupBy(A, a => a.name.slice(0,1))
groupedList = Object.keys(groupBy)
            .sort()
            .map(k => ({key: k, values: grouped[k].sort()}))

console.log(JSON.stringify(groupedList, null, 2))
```

Once the array is re-shaped as per requirement, you can simply use react `.map()` to render the data.

```
groupedList.map(a => `${a.key}: ${a.values.map(v => v.name).join(', ')}`)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this approach. I will give it a try. Cheers!